# Call controller method from directive without defining it on the directive element - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm sure there's a simple answer to this that i've just missed.

http://jsfiddle.net/jonathanwest/pDRxw/3/

Essentially, my directive will contain controls that will always call the same method in a controller which is external to the directive itself.  As you can see from the above fiddle, I can make this work by defining the attribute with the method on the `control` directive, but as that method will always be called from the same button within the directive, I don't want to have to define the method to call.  Instead the directive should know to call the controller `edit` method when that button is pressed.  Therefore, the definition of the `control` would be:

`<control title="Custom Title" />`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually I think doing that straightway using `$parent` is not a recommended way how directives should be defined. Because actually there is no visible dependency on what functions could be called from parent controller, making them little bit harder to re-use.

I do not know actual use case why you need this, but I assume that you use `control` several times and you do not want to copy-paste bunch of attributes that defines some common behavior.

In this case I would recommend little bit other approach: add some directive-container that will define that behavior, and control will require this directive as dependency:

```js
myApp.directive('controlBehavior', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            modifyfunc: '&'
        },        
        controller: function($scope, $timeout) {
            this.modifyfunc = $scope.modifyfunc;
        }
    };
});
myApp.directive('control', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: '^controlBehavior',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            title: "@"
        },
        template : '<div>{{title}}<button ng-click="edit()">Edit</button></div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attr, behavior) {            
            scope.edit = behavior.modifyfunc;   
        }            
    }
});
```

Here is a fiddle to demonstrate this approach: http://jsfiddle.net/7EvpZ/4/

Comment: Interesting approach - thanks for taking the time to do this.  I'm still getting to grips with Angular and discovering the 'right' way to do things.  You are correct on your thoughts about my app - the user can drag and drop multiple controls onto the page, all of which have a common layout with common functions (e.g. close, resize, edit settings etc.), hence wanting to encapsulate those methods into the directive.

Comment: Just imagine your directive as you've exposed it into public - how it declare dependencies, how it react in case if you need to have several "blocks" or your directives with different behaviours... Even if `$parent` way looks simplier, sometimes for maintainability its better to go little bit more complicated but "right" way.

Answer (score 3):

You can access the parent scope by using `$parent` property of the current scope.

http://jsfiddle.net/XEt7D/

Comment: Oh, of course - I knew there would be a simple answer!  Just out of interest, is there a way to achieve this without having to define the pass-through `edit` method in the directive controller?

Comment: Just realised it actually wouldn't make sense to not have the pass-through method in the directive controller, as it's allowing me to access the directive element itself that I can then pass to the controller.  Thanks again.

Comment: `scope` property in the directive is creating the scope for the directive, and I guess you need it.  I think shortest way to achieve the same may be `ng-click="$parent.edit()"` in your template.